# clustered and non-clustered index equivalent in oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, clustered-index

I am coming from MS sql server  where clustered and non clustered index used to play important role.
But looks like there are nothing of this sort under oracle. I am sure there must be some equivalent of
clustered and non clustered index in oracle . Can somebody throw light on this ?

When we say create index in oracle is it equivalent to non clustered index ?

Comment: The equivalent to a clustered index in Oracle is called an "index organized table": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT911

Comment: Index-organized table (IOT) is the nearest thing to it, but it isn't quite the same thing. As I understand it many (most?) tables in SQL Server would have a clustered index, but in Oracle IOTs are used quite sparingly, typically for tables with very few columns other than the PK.

Comment: Have a read of https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:586423377841

Comment: @TonyAndrews: an IOT is exactly the same thing as a clustered index. The whole table data is stored in the index. The reason it's rarely used in Oracle is that it rarely makes sense to do so. See e.g. here https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key for an discussion

Answer (score 0):

Index Organised table in Oracle stores data of the whole table sorted on the basis of say - primary key. So, this is the closest thing to have as clustered Index in Oracle, other than that all other indexes are non-clustered but the Index key for all other indexes are sorted too with Rowid in-front of them which points to the actual data.